# Is a comma needed in a sentence with repeated “to-phrases”?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

Is a comma or any other punctuation needed between each “to-phrase” in a sentence like this one (which is meant to say that the trait has been passed on first from Generation I to Generation II, then from Generation II to Generation III, and so on):

*A. This trait has been passed on from Generation I to Generation II to Generation III and to all subsequent generations.*

If commas are used, the sentence will become …

*B. This trait has been passed on from Generation I to Generation II, to Generation III, and to all subsequent generations.*

Which sentence is correct or more preferable? And what is the grammar rule that covers this matter called?

Comment: I'd say that A defaults to the reading << This trait has been passed on from Generation I to Generation II, then from there on to to Generation III, and then similarly on to all subsequent generations. >> But I'd say B would default to << This trait has been passed on from Generation I to both Generation II and Generation III [...??....] >> were this not illogical from the context. If I had to choose, I'd have to opt for rather awkward A rather than ill-formed (for the intended meaning) B. But simply adding a 'thence' after the first comma rescues better-sounding (B).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for the comment. I think maybe it’s better not to use the compact versions like A & B. Probably, writing it in a longer version like the ones you suggested or the one in parenthesis in my question above is better.